# Back button does not work in header using Framework 7 and intel xdk

Tags: html, intel, intel-xdk, html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 in intel xdk. I need to add back button or link that do the slide transition in the header navbar. I add the following in the html file but the back link does not work.

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="left">
        <a href="#" class="link">
            <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
            <span>Back</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Center</div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="#" class="link">
            <i class="icon icon-bars"></i>
            <span>Menu</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need class `back`.

```
<a href="#" class="link back"> Go back </a>
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/pages-ajax.html#going-back-in-navigation), but I recommend you to read all documentation, not only this section.

Comment: Is the class `back` or `black`? You have it two different ways

Comment: Its `back`. Updated.

Comment: I added this line <a href="#" class="link back"> Go back </a>, with changing # to the page (e.g. index.html) It works but it reload the page with no sliding effect. First, I thought the back link could work automatically and it will make a slide transition

Comment: Hmm yes you should have animation by default. Check you app init for `animatePages: false`. You can read more http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/init-app.html#.Vr2RY_E3Fmo . Search for `animatePages`.

Comment: Thanks @Petroff for your help. The `animatedPages` is `true` by default, I did not change it. Moreover, I set it in the app initialization to true but nothing changed. There is no sliding animation.

Comment: I have no idea what else can break it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In version 3400, just drag the button to the left corner header and when to stay "focused" (orange color) and drop! Then set the button properties.

[image: button on header]